# Derivative of the power of a sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have been trying, by hand, to obtain the second derivative with repect to $t$ of the function $f(t)$, shown below, but I'm having a ***great*** deal of difficulty. The function is actually the characteristic function for a particular kind of descretized Gaussian probability density function described by Widrow in his 1958 M.I.T. thesis entitled *"A study of rough amplitude quantization by means of Nyquist sampling theory"*.

Ultimately, I want to evaluate the second derivative at $t=0$ and obtain an expression for the second moment.

How can I sensibly tackle in Mathematica the problem of obtaining the second derivative?

$$
f(t) = 
    \bigg(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \pi \left( \frac{t}{n \phi} + k \right)}
      {\pi \left( \frac{t}{n \phi} + k \right)} \times
      \exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{t}{n} + k \phi)^2 \sigma^2 + i \mu (\frac{t}{n} + k \phi) \right]\bigg)^n ,$$
where $\phi = 2 \pi/q$, and $t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, q \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \mu \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{+}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Or, in Mathematica code:

```
f[t_]:=(Sum[(Sin[Pi*((t/(n*phi)) + k)]/(Pi*((t/(n*phi)) + k)))*
    Exp[(-1/2)*((t/n) + k*phi)^2*(sigma^2) + 
      I*mu*((t/n) + k*phi)], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}])^n
```

Comment: Write $f(t)=(\sum_k g(k, t) )^n$ and compute the derivative $g'(k, t)$ with MA. Then $f'(t)=n (\sum_k g(k, t) )^{n-1} \sum_k g'(k, t)$.